# Nagios After samples are taken run a process

Tags: nagios

Trying to set up a nagios process which, after it samples my servers, it runs a process.  What I want this process to do is write the resultant data to a log file, something I can post to another process (like splunk, but NOT splunk)  Basically, I want to take each sample returned and send it to another URL.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the events sent to another log in standard syslog format (i.e. for Splunk) just set use_syslog=1 in nagios.conf (http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html).  You can the configure syslog to send the the messages to a separate logfile and/or another syslog host.

Answer (score 0):

Theres probably a better way to do this, but I would just use some tool like sec [http://simple-evcorr.sourceforge.net/ ]  or write your own handler that tails the nagios log file. It has all the raw info you need in a standard format.